# Is there a more direct/efficient way for a skip button?

Tags: forms, buttons, multi-step, optional-fields

I am currently working on a information request flow.
The information needed is subdivided into 2 parts: the contact information (required) and some more details which are not necessary but add value to the request.

This is the flow right now:
[image]
*The user clicks on the request button and the 2-step pop-up opens. In the first step he can chose to directly send his request without additional information.*

**My question to you is:** is this the best way to enable the user to skip the last step or is it a problem that he does not know what he is skipping? Are there some good alternative flows I did not think of?

Addition: The requests without details also have a great value.

Comment: I think it is fine, but you should tell the user that they can always fill out the details that they skipped later in the user account details section/wherever you're allowing users to edit their contact details.

Comment: Yes, that is the plan! There will be some explanation about that in the second step.

Comment: Well just looking off the picture, there's one glaring problem I already see...

Comment: At the very least the "skip" button should also be on the skippable step.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think in your case the wizard pattern is not a very good idea. I would recommend adding an extra button on your initial screen "ADD MORE DETAILS" above the SEND button (if you place the additional details below in small letters it will be probably missed).

Add a label "OPTIONAL" so that users know they can skip the additional step.

When the users select the more details, navigate to your second screen as you show. Something like the following :

[image]

Comment: I think this is indeed the best way to go, thanks for sharing your answer. I will look into testing different button labels on that as I wish to make it as motivating as possible. :)

Comment: @IaEm you can also try to make the Send button less prominent (together with a more appropriate wording)

Answer (score 3):

As a user, filling multiple contact forms is really annoying, irrespective of the UI. Why not restructure the entire contact form as a single page. There is a reason why every registration form is a single-page process, which is to ensure that the process of asking data from the user does not irritate him.

Use the conventional '*required field (*)*' concept, but focus on an attractive, but clean UI. The user will go through the form, and fill only what is necessary, and may even fill more if the UI is neat and clean.

I would never recommend a multiple-page contact form. You could bring in some user interactive features, like button, radio boxes and drop downs, but make sure you don't try and extract too much data from the user, just for the sake of asking them details.

Collect only the details you actually need, say Name, Email, Number and provide only a couple of '*not mandatory*' fields for the user. The user will know automatically that he need not fill in those details. You need not tell him that he has the option to skip certain fields, because it will be obvious to them, provided you take the '*required field*' concept.

As far as UX is concerned, the lesser content, the merrier the page.

Comment: To add: It's considered better to mark the optional fields as optional, rather than marking the mandatory fields (with a *). https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?725

Comment: That's a matter of perspective, but it is also a very valid suggestion. Thank you for the information.

Comment: True, in the end we don't know what works best in this situation until it's tested!

Comment: @Wendy that post is actually comparing whether it is better to use the full word "optional" rather than an asterisk (or other visual cue) for the optional fields. Although, granted, the page title suggests otherwise.

Comment: Let's not forget that from a data protection standpoint (at least in the UK) you should only be storing the "minimum amount" of personal data to provide the service

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you display it now causes unneccessary confusion. You only mention adding details in the progress bar, which is something that can be easily overlooked. So it is unclear what the difference is between the two options and what changes if you continue by pushing next. If you add this missing info to your button, you'll clear things up. Something like 'next step: add details' or 'step 2: add details' if you add more visual cues that you're currently on step 1. The progress bar alone doesn't really convey it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I would flip the form around and have the request details first and allow the user to skip to the contact details section. This prioritizes the user issue details first (when a user may be more willing to type) and then collects the necessary information to help them finish the request. I see this as a 'helpful pain point' where guiding the user into providing more details is both in the best interest of the user and the person on the receiving end.

Not directly related to the question, it may also make sense to have a 'category' drop down to help pin down a category that the request belongs to. This is easy to use for the user and also gives the person being contacted an idea of the urgency and nature of the contact.

Answer (score 0):

I second DesignerAnalyst's answer.

However, if you're looking to streamline it even more, I'd consider two changes:

(1) Keep the Send button as the only CTA. My reasoning:  You want users to get in touch. Anything that blocks that is risky. So by providing a clear CTA that puts them in touch with you, you're removing obstacles for the people who don't want to add further information.

(2) Hide the optional data fields but have them reveal themselves as the user interacts with the UI. My reasoning: People don't like to waste work. A bit like the the sunk cost fallacy. By progressively disclosing the optional fields, you're only presenting complexity after the user has finished with the core info and the user has already started the work so they might be more inclined to continue with these optionals.

TLDR: Progressively disclose the optional data and keep to one CTA.